# how do i count form validation errors in php?

Tags: php, forms

this is a page where form values are pre-filled from a mysql database.  people can edit the form and update database record.

i am checking if fields are left empty and creating error variables.  when form is submitted and page is re-rendered, the error variables (of the ones that were left empty) become true, and so i then echo the error messages on the page.

this is just the part that echos the error messages, not the other parts that grab database fields, then creates error variables, then renders variables back to page upon page refreshing, etc.

```
<?php
    if ($error != '') {
        echo '<div class="error top">';
        echo $error;
        echo "<ul>";
        if ($clientnameErr != '') { echo $clientnameErr; }
        if ($ponumberErr != '') { echo $ponumberErr; }
        if ($dropdate1Err != '') { echo $dropdate1Err; }
        if ($dropqty1Err != '') { echo $dropqty1Err; }
        if ($postage1Err != '') { echo $postage1Err; }
        echo '</ul></div>';
    }
?>
```

so i would like to count all the errors that are true and have that number as a variable.  how do i do that?

so for example if clientname, ponumber, and dropdate1 were left empty, then that would be 3 empties and error messages for $clientnameErr, $ponumberErr, and $dropdate1Err would echo out, because those 3 if statements would be true, so i would need a variable to equal 3, so i can print that out.

actually i'm going to go ahead and show how it's making certain fields required, then creating the error variables, just in case you need it to solve the above.

```
if ($clientname == '' || $ponumber == '' || $dropdate1 == '' || $dropqty1 == '' || $postage1 == '') {
  $error = '<p>ERROR: Please fill in all required fields!</p>';
  if ($clientname == '') { $clientnameErr = '<li>Missing Client Name!</li>'; }
  if ($ponumber == '') { $ponumberErr = '<li>Missing PO Number!</li>'; } 
  if ($dropdate1 == '') { $dropdate1Err = '<li>Missing Drop Date 1!</li>'; }
  if ($dropqty1 == '') { $dropqty1Err = '<li>Missing Drop Quantity 1!</li>'; }
  if ($postage1 == '') { $postage1Err = '<li>Missing Postage 1!</li>'; }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an array to hold the errors. Then you can simply use `count()` on it to get your error total:

```
$errors = array();
if ($clientname == '') {
    $errors['clientname'] = '<li>Missing Client Name!</li>'
}
if ($ponumber == '') {
    $errors['ponumber'] = '<li>Missing PO Number!</li>'
}

$numErrors = count($errors);
if ($numErrors > 0) {
  echo '<p>Total errors: ' . $numErrors . '</p>';
  $error = '<p>ERROR: Please fill in all required fields!</p>';
  echo "<ul>";
  echo implode("\n", $errors);
  echo "</ul>";
}
```

Comment: Might be better to loop through the errors (`for ($errors as $key => $error) { echo $error; }`) :)

Comment: When displaying them, yes. That would be the best way to go about it.

Comment: page renders as empty.  is this part right?  if ($clientname == '') { $errors['errorKey'] = '<li>Missing Client Name!</li>' }
if ($ponumber == '') { $errors['errorKey'] = '<li>Missing PO Number!</li>' }
if ($dropdate1 == '') { $errors['errorKey'] = '<li>Missing Drop Date 1!</li>' }
if ($dropqty1 == '') { $errors['errorKey'] = '<li>Missing Drop Quantity 1!</li>' }
if ($postage1 == '') { $errors['errorKey'] = '<li>Missing Postage 1!</li>' }

Comment: I see at least two problems with that code. I see my sample error in there which should not be there and you are overriding all of your errors in your array because you are not changing the keys.

Comment: so like this?
if ($clientname == '') { $errors[0] = '<li>Missing Client Name!</li>' }

if ($ponumber == '') { $errors[1] = '<li>Missing PO Number!</li>' }

if ($dropdate1 == '') { $errors[2] = '<li>Missing Drop Date 1!</li>' }

if ($dropqty1 == '') { $errors[3] = '<li>Missing Drop Quantity 1!</li>' }

if ($postage1 == '') { $errors[4] = '<li>Missing Postage 1!</li>' }

Comment: I updated my answer to give you a better example. But your new try looks like you are on the right track.

Comment: still empty/blank/white page.  this may work, but not the way my page is built and renders upon different scenarios, such as "if form submitted", "if form not submitted", "if id in url doesn't exist", "if id in url has been left out completely", things like that.

Comment: Sounds like a parse error. Make sure display_errors is turned on.

Comment: seems that missing semicolons were the culprit.  $errors['clientname'] = '<li>Missing Client Name!</li>'; $errors['ponumber'] = '<li>Missing PO Number!</li>';